# How to print directly in windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, printing

I'm using a HTML code to print some content exists into a div, when i click a button in the browser it prints this content, the thing here that before printing a dialog box appears to choose the printer but i want it to print directly using the default printer attached to the system.

**p.s.** it's not about the browser as the browser button is used only for testing but in real i'll just print the contents of the div directly.

*The code i'm using:*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function printDiv(divID) {0.
            //Get the HTML of div
            var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
            //Get the HTML of whole page
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

            //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
            document.body.innerHTML = 
              "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
              divElements + "</body>";

            //Print Page
            window.print(false);

            //Restore orignal HTML
            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;


        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="printablediv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Blue; height: 200px">
        ay klam
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print 1st Div" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand your P.S. - you mean ignore the fact there's a form button on the page or ignore the fact you're using a browser? If you're using a browser you'll always have to go through the browser-defined print process I'd think.

Comment: @Rup i meant if there is a non-browser solution it's OK for me

Comment: How are you planning to display your HTML without a browser?  Are you going to distribute an application?

Comment: Off topic, but the Javascript in your example makes me cringe in various different ways.

Comment: @EricBrown yea, i'll distribute an application but it's not just about HTML, if anyone knows how to do that with other language it 'll be ok with me

Comment: Languages that can print directly in Windows, without having to go through the dialog box? Sure, all of them. As long as they can use Windows APIs.